# Mailgun configure for PHP

Tags: php, curl, mailgun

I'm new on mailgun, there i found php code but unable to understand all for this asking help on here. please help me anyone.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

$mgClient = new Mailgun('key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0');
$domain = "samples.mailgun.org";

$result = $mgClient->sendMessage("$domain",
  array('from'    => 'Excited User <excited@samples.mailgun.org>',
        'to'      => 'Mailgun Devs <devs@mailgun.net>',
        'subject' => 'Hello',
        'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'));
```

But where i find autoload.php. please help me anyone. also their girhub project showing error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read their installation instructions? If you followed the steps, you'd have the autoload.php generated for you by Composer.

Answer (score 0):

If you go [here](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php), you will find all instructions for sending email through MailGun.

Click on Library download to download all the MailGun files with the Composer.

Then you just have to place the autoload.php correctly in your Mailgun folder to match with your code, and it'll work like a charm.

Note that the Mailgun's response is in JSON, use

`echo "<pre>";
    print_r($results);
 echo "</pre>";`

to print your results in an array way. It's easier to read and to analyse.